# Issues with Glyphs in arabic fonts

Tags: fonts, arabic

I am writing a document in Arabic language. I am required to use the "Simplified Arabic" font.

https://www.wfonts.com/font/simplified-arabic

I am using Lualatex.Upon adding glyphs to the same word, the letters apear disconnected with slight white spaces between them. As shown in the MWE with words having glyphs apear disconnected and the same words without glyphs apear normally. How can I resolve this issue?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,margin=2.5cm,bindingoffset=0.5cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[hidelinks,colorlinks=true,breaklinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref} 


\usepackage[bidi=basic,layout=lists.tabular]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=ar,mapdigits,main]{arabic}
\babelprovide[import=en,language=Default]{english}


\babelfont{rm}{Latin Modern Roman}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}{simplified arabic}
\babelfont[english]{rm}{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}

مُفَصَّلِ
:
مفصل
\newline
مُتَشَدِدَ
:
متشدد

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: use harfbuzz `\babelfont[arabic]{rm}[Renderer=Harfbuzz]{simplified arabic}`.

Comment: Thx this resolved the issue.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been solved with the comment.